# KafkaConsumer with sasl_mechanism "OAUTHBEARER" not calling token() function

Tags: python, apache-kafka, oauth, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to get a minimal **kafka** consumer working, using kafka-python. Authentication is via OAuth.

I created a TokenProvider class, which is working fine. Any time, token() is called, it will check whether there is a current token and if not, fetch one from the OAuth URL.

```
>>> from myoauth import TokenProvider
>>> tp = TokenProvider(instance="test", verbose=True)
>>> print(tp.token()[:20]+"...")
Request to https://<hostname>/auth/realms/kafka-flow/protocol/openid-connect/token:
Response 200 OK
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIs...
```

Code for the minimal consumer that prints the available kafka topics is below:

```
import ssl
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
from myoauth import TokenProvider

bootstrap_server = '<hostname>:443'
consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers=[bootstrap_server],
                         security_protocol='SSL',
                         ssl_context=ssl._create_unverified_context(),
                         sasl_mechanism="OAUTHBEARER",
                         sasl_oauth_token_provider=TokenProvider(instance="test", verbose=True),
                         client_id="kafka-client",
                         group_id="kafka-group",
                        )

print("Consumer created, {} topics found".format(len(consumer.topics())))
for topic in sorted(consumer.topics()):
    print(topic)
```

The output is surpisingly:

```
$ ./get_topics.py
Consumer created, 0 topics found
```

I assume, the issue is with the oauth, as the `token()` function of the TokenProvider class is never called (no `Request to https://...` output). And without token, it is obvious that the consumer does not have access to any topics.

Any ideas how to solve this appreciated.

`kafka-python` version is 2.0.2. `python` is 3.6.8.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. `security_protocol` should be `SASL_SSL`, as it was `SSL` only, the SASL  authentication was not triggered.